# changing rally basic dropdown menus after display

Tags: drop-down-menu, rally

I have a rally.sdk.ui.basic.Dropdown menu in a Rally App that I would like to change based on user input.  So I will call display() on the dropdown menu, and then later I want to change the contents of that menu.

Has anybody done this?  When I try, it crashes.  I've also tried calling destroy() on the dropdown menu and then calling display() on a new menu that I allocate, but that crashes as well with an obscure dojo error.

Any suggestions on how to change dropdown menus on the fly?

I've included a very stripped down example below of trying to destroy and then re-display the menu:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Incoming Defects by Severity</title>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7" >
    <meta name="Name"    content="Defects by Severity" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://rally1.rallydev.com/apps/1.29/sdk.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function DefectChart() {
            this.display = function() {
                var defectVersionDropdown;
                var count = 1;

                function makeDefectChart(results){
                    initDefectVersionDropdown();
                };

                function renderPage() {
                    var queryConfig = [];
                    var startDate   = '2011-06-06';
                    var endDate     = '2012-02-02';
                    var queryArray  = ['CreatedDate >= "' + startDate + '"', 'CreatedDate <= "' + endDate + '"'];
                    var versionFilter       = defectVersionDropdown ? defectVersionDropdown.getDisplayedValue() : 'ALL';
                        if (versionFilter != 'ALL') {
                            queryArray.push('FoundInBuild contains "' + versionFilter + '"');
                        }   
// console.log(queryArray);
                    queryConfig.push({
                        type : 'Defects',
                        key  : 'defects',
                        query:  rally.sdk.util.Query.and(queryArray),
                        fetch: 'Severity,State,LastUpdateDate,CreationDate,OpenedDate,AcceptedDate,LastUpdateDate,ClosedDate,Environment,FoundInBuild'
                    });

                    rallyDataSource.findAll(queryConfig, makeDefectChart);
                }

                function defectVersionChange(sender, eventArgs) {
                    var version = eventArgs.value;

                    renderPage();
                }

                function initDefectVersionDropdown() {
                    if (defectVersionDropdown != null) {
                        defectVersionDropdown.destroy();
                        defectVersionDropdown = null;
                    }

                    if (defectVersionDropdown == null) {
                  console.log('initDefectVersionDropdown'); 
                        count++;
                        var menuItems   = [{label: "ALL", value: "ALL"}];
                            for (var i=0; i < count; i++) {
                                menuItems.push({label: count, value: count});
                            }
                        var config  = {
                                label:  "Found In Version:",
                                items:  menuItems
                             };

                        defectVersionDropdown   = new rally.sdk.ui.basic.Dropdown(config);

                        defectVersionDropdown.addEventListener("onChange", defectVersionChange);
                        defectVersionDropdown.display("defectVersionDiv");
                    }
                }

                var workspaceOid    = '__WORKSPACE_OID__';  if (workspaceOid.toString().match(/__/))    { workspaceOid  = XXX; }
                var projectOid      = '__PROJECT_OID__';    if (projectOid.toString().match(/__/))      { projectOid    = XXX; }

                rallyDataSource = new rally.sdk.data.RallyDataSource(   workspaceOid,
                                                                        projectOid,
                                                                        '__PROJECT_SCOPING_UP__',
                                                                        '__PROJECT_SCOPING_DOWN__');
                initDefectVersionDropdown();
                renderPage();
            }
        }

        function getDataAndShow() {
            var defectChart = new DefectChart();

            defectChart.display();
        }

        function loadRally() {
            rally.addOnLoad(getDataAndShow);
        }

        loadRally();
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="defectVersionDiv"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Destroying the old one creating and displaying a new one is the correct way to do this.  This is a common pattern when developing apps using the App SDK.  If you provide a code snipped along with the dojo error you are getting the community can probably be of better assistance.

Comment: I've added a stripped down code snipped that fails crashes in firefox when display is called the second time after a rally query completes.   The error I get is: dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore: The json data provided by the creation arguments is malformed. Items within the list have identifier: [value]. Value collided: [2] addOnLoad(_1b="rally1.rallydev...component_01-17-2012.js";, _1c=undefined)sdk.js (line 8) addOnLoad()

Comment: In the code, I init the menu, then do a Rally query for defects.  When I get a result, I destroy the menu, and create a new one-- in the example code I just build up a meaningless menu with numbers in it as an example.  One interesting note:  If I destroy and re-create the menu, but the menu has the same items in it as before, it doesn't crash.  Only if the menu is different does it crash.  Wierd...

Comment: Your current code is crashing because there is a collision in values in the dropdown- they have to be unique.  (The code example has two objects with value = 2).